# sIFR3 smoothing and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sifr, flash, javascript

i've started to use sIFR3.

I don't know how to turn on smoothing of font. Do i need to change it in my font.swf file?

In FF3 it work perfect, everything is okay, but when i turn on my IE8, nothing changes. Even live example doesn't work (http://work.likeaninja.co.uk/sifr/demo/). What's going on?

My Flash Player is "WIN 10,1,51,95" (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html). I thinks it's beta, but it shouldn't change anything. Help!

Comment: "I thinks it's beta, but it shouldn't change anything. Help!" LMAO @ that. Famous last words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the Flash install is somehow corrupted and Flash can't be detected.